# putting arrowhead in the middle of an arrow

Tags: xy-pic, xymatrix

I have the following graph with `\xymatrix`. I want to place arrowheads in the middle of each arrow, as you can see the result is messy:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix  @=220pt {
  u \ar@/^3.5pc/[r]^{\alpha_{d(u, v)}}  \ar@/^2.4pc /@{.>}[r] \ar@/^1.0 pc/[r]^{\alpha_{1}} \ar@{.}@(l,d) \ar@(ur,dr)^{\gamma_{1}} \ar@(r,d)^{\gamma_{2}} \ar@(dr,dl)^{\gamma_{3}} 
\ar@(l,u)^{\gamma_{d(u, u)}}
        &
v   \ar@/^1.0 pc/[l]^{\beta_1}   \ar@/^2.5pc /@{.>}[l]   \ar@/^3.5pc/[l]^{\beta_{d(v, u)}} 
\ar@{.}@(l,d) \ar@(ur,dr)^{\tau_{1}} \ar@(r,d)^{\tau_{2}} \ar@(dr,dl)^{\tau_{3}} 
 \ar@(l,u) ^(0.6) {\tau_{d(v, v)}}  }   
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add an arrow head in the middle of an arrow like this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
  \xymatrix  @=220pt {
    u \ar@/^3.5pc/@{}[r]^{\alpha_{d(u, v)}} |{\SelectTips{cm}{}\object@{>}}
    & v
  }   
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the amazing help. It worked very well. I have another problem regarding this graph. I've searched a lot, and it seems there is no solution with \xymatrix. I want all the loops around "u" to be on one side, and I should be able to make the length of a loop longer. Is this possible with \xymatrix?

Comment: @ZahraNazemian If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: I did: "making loops longer with \xymatix"

Comment: I'd recommend using the `cmtip` option to `xy`, so all arrow tips will be good, as opposed to the very disputable version without the option. In this case you don't need `\SelectTips{cm}{}`, of course.